# PHP test whether date is the first element of an array

Tags: php, arrays, testing

Given the array below, how do I test whether the variable `$target_date` is equal to the first element of the array?  This is the result I am looking for:

```
$target_date = [Nov 18, 2011] return yes;
$target_date = [Nov 22, 2011] return no;
$target_date = [Nov 29, 2011] return no;
```

Here is the array:

```
Array
(
[Nov 18, 2011] => Array
    (
        [C] => 100
        [I] => 100
        [M] => 100
    )
[Nov 22, 2011] => Array
    (
        [C] => 200
        [I] => 200
    )
[Nov 29, 2011] => Array
    (
        [C] => 300
        [I] => -300
    )
)
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

That's not the first element in the array, it's the *key*. Hence:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $values) {
    if ($key == $target_date) {
        /* Yes! */
    } else {
        /* No! */
    }
}
```

If you want to look at the *first key* directly without looping:

```
current(array_keys($array)) == $target_date
```

Comment: Even better: `key($array) == $target_date`. Technically this is dependent on the current position of the array iterator, but looping without `foreach` is so rare that it will never matter.

Comment: @Jon I'd just put that as a disclaimer, "works unless you modified the array pointer", instead of "will never matter", but yes, overall agreed. :)